# Concatenate with a group by in Spring JPA

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 3 tables:

```
Id1 Value1
1  Foo
2  Bar
```

```
Fk1 Fk2
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
```

```
Id2  Value2
1    Some
2    Other
3    Ok
```

I need a query to output this

```
Foo | Some, Other, Ok
Bar | Some, Other
```

I'm using Oracle with Spring and `@Query`, I found the function `LISTAGG` which is what I need but Spring doesn't recognize it, is there any other way to achieve this using only one query?

Comment: "I found the function LISTAGG which is what I need but Spring doesn't recognize it" - If all else fails, you can do a native query. Spring Data supports that just fine.

Comment: Alternatively use an database *view* that projects the required data.

Comment: I also need pagination in this query so I'd like to use `@Query` if that is possible